# jQuery Datatables Server side pagination with custom HTTP POST request and response

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have worked on one issue for last two days.
I'm using jQuery and DataTables in a page, which fetches data from a server and populates tables quite happily.
I need to make a change for requests from dataTables library to fetch data from the server happen.

Is it possible to make a jquery ajax post request without defined param list mention in link below?

https://datatables.net/usage/server-side

This is my json POST request:

```
{"page_number":1,"page_size":10}
```

and this is my server response:

```
{
 "status": 200,
 "message": "Users retrieved successfully.",
  "users": [Assumelistofusers],
  "total_count": 50,
  "total_page_count": 5
}
```

I have found that, in YUI Library for DataTable Control (beta), there is good example of server side pagination.
refer the link:

http://examples.mashupguide.net/lib/yui_2.3.0/examples/datatable/dt_serverpagination.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to do this, because you will loose all the filtering and sorting if you explicitly exclude these parameters that are there for a reason.

But, yes, you can use the fnServerData function to define you own calls and methods to your server sided datasource.

```
$('#dt').dataTable({
"bServerSide": true,
"sAjaxSource": "my_serverdata.script",
"fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
  var mydata=[]
  mydata.push( { "name": "page_number", "value": 1 } );
  mydata.push( { "name": "page_size", "value": 10 } );
   //here comes a basic jQuery helper function to handle your ajax call.
   //of course you can replace it with any other ajax handler
   //has nothing to do with dataTables
   $.ajax({
    "dataType": 'json',
    "type": "POST",
    "url": sSource,
    "data": mydata,
    "success": fnCallback
  });
}
});
```

Here the usual `aoData` is totally overwritten with the custom array `mydata`. This will be posted to your server:

```
 page_number    1
 page_size  10
```

Now you just need to write a function for the success handler which maps the server response to the expected variables (`iTotalRecords = total_count`, `aaData = users` etc) and then call `fnCallback` to process everything.

Of course this needs some fiddling around to find out how to fill out the expected server response. But this should work.

I can't produce a Fiddle or a Plunker because of ajax.

Be aware that this would only make sense if you can't change the server sided script. Also note, that in the same way i create a new array mydata, you can also push extra post data to `aoData` and just ignore the additional parameters on your server side.

BTW: Returning `total_page_count` is kinda useless since this can be computed on the client side pretty easily.